# Bind tooltip to a marker as a result of turf.js distance method in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, markers, turf, tooltip

I'm trying to simply put the results of the distance variable in the tooltip but keep getting undefined. I don't understand what's happening.

```
function findDistanceToCentroid(countyPolygon, searchedFeature) {
                
    // convert Leaflet layer to geojson with Leaflet toGeoJSON() method
    var centCounty = countyPolygon.toGeoJSON();

    // get centroid of county polygon
    var centroid = turf.centerOfMass(centCounty);

    // create marker from centroid
    var lon = centroid.geometry.coordinates[0];
    var lat = centroid.geometry.coordinates[1];
    
    var marker = L.marker([lat, lon]).addTo(map).bindTooltip(`${distance} Miles`).openTooltip();

    var distanceGeoJSON = marker.toGeoJSON();

    var from = searchedFeature
    var to = distanceGeoJSON
    var options = {units: 'miles'};

    var distance = turf.distance(from, to, options);
    console.log(distance)
}
```

Comment: Do you get undefined only in tooltip or also in console log?

Comment: @TomazicM the distance result logs fine - undefined is when I bind the tooltip. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that you are setting content of marker tooltip too early, when distance is not calculated/defined yet.

Just use `.bindTooltip` after distance is calculated:

```
var marker = L.marker([lat, lon]).addTo(map);

var distanceGeoJSON = marker.toGeoJSON();

var from = searchedFeature
var to = distanceGeoJSON
var options = {units: 'miles'};

var distance = turf.distance(from, to, options);
marker.bindTooltip(`${distance} Miles`).openTooltip();
```

Comment: I swear I tried this - it works! Thank you! @TomazicM